# Mobile navbar with 100% window height regardless of content

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, navigationbar

I have a mobile version of a page. The content is enough that user has to scroll on his mobile device. When clicking an icon the mobile navigation bar slides in from left side and `body` gets `overflow: hidden;` so content does not scroll anymore. Is there a way to make the navigation bar 100% height of window (instead of document) so that user can scroll inside navigation bar furthermore?
At the moment slide-in and height of navigation is controlled by Javascript, but I'm looking for a CSS solution. Can anyone help?

```
// CSS
#mobile_nav {
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    z-index: 10000;
    overflow: auto;
}

// JS
jQuery("#mobile_button").on("click", function() {
    jQuery("#mobile_nav")
        .css({ height: jQuery(window).height() });
        .stop(true)
        .animate({ left: 0 })
    ;
    jQuery("body").css({ overflow: "hidden" });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Viewport units for that like this:

```
    height: 100vh;
```

You could check the browser support for this css property [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).